# Amazon Product Advertising API does not return descriptions from domains other than .com

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

ItemLookup or ItemSearch requests to, e.g. ecs.amazonaws.jp, that look like,

```
http://ecs.amazonaws.jp/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=MYKEY&AssociateTag=MYKEY&IdType=ISBN&IncludeReviewsSummary=&ItemId=9784087716061&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Large&SearchIndex=Books&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2015-06-09T08%3A10%3A12Z&Version=2011-08-02&Signature=SIGNATURE
```

fail to return "product description" with the response XML file while the web page of this item does have description.

The error (if that's what it is) has never occurred with requests to http://ecs.amazonaws.com, and persisted with requests to .jp, .de and other domains.

Any idea how this happened and, how can I get product descriptions with the [Amazon Product Advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html) when the domain isn't .com? The last thing I want to do is to screen scrape webpages.

PS I have tried ResponseGroup=EditorialReview, ResponseGroup=Large,EditorialReview to no avail.